# Issue with EntityFramework 6 (Code First) SQL DB Identity interaction - EF tries to insert explicit value in identity column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I have a SQL database, with a table consisting of a few columns, with a 'user_id' column, set as PK and identity.

This is the code for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
[user_id]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[firstname] NVARCHAR (25)  NOT NULL,
[lastname]  NVARCHAR (25)  NOT NULL,
[title]     NVARCHAR (10)  NOT NULL,
[email]     NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[password]  NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([user_id] ASC)
);
```

When trying to save a new object in the DB, it produces the error

```
SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 
'Users' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

The object being saved is not given a 'user_id'.

The DBContext for the 'user_id' is:

```
entity.Property(e => e.UserId).HasColumnName("user_id");
```

and has been autogenerated by EFCorePowerTools.

The actual user class has the property 'UserID', which is bound to 'user_id' in the DBContext.

```
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
```

The idea is to let the SQL DB handle the key generation.

Manually inserting via queries works perfectly, so the issue must lie in the EF implementation.

So far, I've tried:

Making the 'UserID' in 'User' nullable,

Having only '[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] as the annotation for 'UserID'

Remaking the DB, and then remaking the DBContext

For some reason, even when the 'UserID' in 'User' is annotated with [NotMapped], I get the same error, which leads me to believe there's an issue in the actual DBContext binding.

Here's the full DBContext for 'Users':

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.UserId).HasColumnName("user_id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Email)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("email")
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.Firstname)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("firstname")
                .HasMaxLength(25);

            entity.Property(e => e.Lastname)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("lastname")
                .HasMaxLength(25);

            entity.Property(e => e.Password)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("password")  
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            entity.Property(e => e.Title)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("title")
                .HasMaxLength(10);
        });
```

And all of the 'User' class:

```
public partial class User : DomainAppBase, IStorable
{
    public User()
    {
        Leads = new HashSet<Lead>();
    }

    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public override void SetDefaultValues()
    {
        UserId = NullKey;
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Lead> Leads { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public new int Key => UserId;
}
```

Any help or pointers would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define the Key as  `modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(o => o.UserId );    entity.Property(e => e.UserId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().HasColumnName("user_id")` while defining Entity model.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. Much appreciated :)

Comment: I will post that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update the model builder as

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
{
   entity.HasKey(o => o.UserId );
   entity.Property(e => e.UserId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().HasColumnName("user_id")
 ...................
```

`ValueGeneratedOnAdd` enables to generate a value when adding a new entity.